# Looking up values in an org spreadsheet

Tags: org-mode, spreadsheet

I imagine it would be possible, with the tables

```
| food    | kcal/hg |
|---------+---------|
| sausage |     281 |
```

and

```
    | food    |   g | kcal |
    |---------+-----+------|
    | sausage | 100 |      |
```

that is, with a table of food names and kcal/hg values and a
table of names and g values, automatically to calculate the kcal
values in the second list.  But how exactly is that to be done?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the lisp function `memq` for the lookup as demonstrated in the Org example below.
I use the [Literal mode switch](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Formula-syntax-for-Lisp) `L`.
This imposes the restriction that there are only one-word identifier in the `food` column.

Furthermore I use `quote` to avoid evaluation of the symbols in the table formula.

Please, use the table debugger to see what is going on (`Tbl` menu item `Debug Formulas`).

```org
#+NAME: kcal_per_hg
| food      | kcal/hg |
|-----------+---------|
| sausage   |     281 |
| something |     100 |
| other     |     200 |

and

| food    |   g |  kcal |
|---------+-----+-------|
| sausage | 100 | 281.0 |
| other   | 123 | 246.0 |
#+TBLFM: $3='(* 0.01 $2 (cadr (memq (quote $1) (quote (remote(kcal_per_hg,@I$1..@II$2))))));L
```

Note that this solution is tailored to your special problem since the words are actually looked-up in the full table `kcal_per_hg`.

There follows a more general but also more complicated variant.
It only searches the first column of the two-column table `kcal_per_hg` for food.

```org
#+NAME: kcal_per_g
| food      | kcal/g |
|-----------+--------|
| something |    100 |
| sausage   |    281 |
| other     |    200 |

and

| food    |   g |  kcal |
|---------+-----+-------|
| other   | 123 | 246.0 |
| sausage | 100 | 281.0 |
#+TBLFM: $3='(* $2 0.01 (cl-loop for p on (quote (remote(kcal_per_g,@I$1..@II$2))) by #'cddr if (eq (quote $1) (car p)) return (cadr p)));L
```

If each row of the table to be searched has `N` columns instead of two you can replace `cddr` with `(apply-partially #'nthcdr N)`.